# Hover over nested div doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out why, when I hover over a specific div, nothing happens, but if I hover over the parent div, the cursor changes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="navDiv">

    <div class="logbookDropdown">
        <p class="dropdownText">Logbooks</p>
        <div class="dropdownIcon"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="logbookDiv">
        <div class="logbookNameDiv">
            <h1 class="logbookName">YOUR</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="logbookEndDiv">
            <h1 class="logbookEnd">Logbook</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.logbookDropdown:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The above CSS does not work--meaning nothing happens, the cursor doesn't change.

But if say the following:

```
.navDiv:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

... it does work, as in: the cursor changes.

Not sure why this is happening..

Comment: I tried the code in a jsfiddle and it seems to work as intended?

Comment: I also tried it in a jsFiddle and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/n31h4b2z/

Comment: I had `float:left` in the CSS class for .logbookDropdown. But since I had to get rid of that, I am not sure how to fix the mess it caused in the layout

Comment: I'm running it in chrome right now and it's working. Is it possible you're overriding the rule with some other code?

Answer (score 0):

I had `float:left` in the CSS class for `.logbookDropdown`. But since I had to get rid of that, I am not sure how to fix the mess it caused in the layout

Answer (score 0):

The above css is perfectly working fine in my chrome browser. Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/st59fzvu/).

```
.navDiv:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Tips to debug:**

1. You might have other conflicting css rules that is overriding this style.
2. Check if it is browser specific issue. Sometimes things doesnt work as expected in different browser.